# How should I store the same data as two different units of measurement in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

Our program is storing spatial data as WGS84 (longitude, latitude) in MongoDB. However, a component our program interacts with uses UTM. Because converting the data is too inaccurate (precision loss is nontrivial) even with using library code, we are thinking of storing the data as both WGS84 and UTM to do away with the conversion. I'm aware that MongoDB uses WGS84 internallyfor spatial queries, so storing UTM is purely for speed and accuracy reasons (i.e. if said component queries spatial data from our DB, we could easily return it in UTM).

Is this a good idea, or is there a better alternative? I'm concerned that data integrity may be compromised due to duplication of data (if the WGS84 data changes, then UTM must be updated as well, and vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

If the available libraries are too inaccurate for your use cases, I would recommend storing the `longitude` and `latitude` as arrays, containing 2 values - one for WGS84 and one for UTM.

The advantage of this approach is that it allows you to define some other attributes for those measurements that can be stored as part of the array object members.

Moreover, as this would be a bounded array, it would have no impact in terms of query performance.

```
{
    ...
    longitude: [
        {
            format: "WGS84",
            value: 123456
        },
        {
            format: "UTM",
            value: 654321
        }
    ],
    latitude: [
        {
            format: "WGS84",
            value: 123456
        },
        {
            format: "UTM",
            value: 654321
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can store them as an object with 2 attributes - one for each format.

```
{
    ...
    longitude: {
        WGS84: 123456,
        UTM: 654321
    },
    latitude: {
        WGS84: 123456,
        UTM: 654321
    },
    ...
}
```

However, as you mentioned, in terms of data integrity, the responsibility of keeping the values in sync now falls under the application component.

Therefore, you need to implement some sort of a rule engine in your application to accurately update both values when one of them changes.